# Can anyone explain how bytes memory can be converted to address type in solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, solidity-0.6.x

when I am using below function to convert bytes memory to address, this is working fine.

Suppose input to the function is 0X000000000000000000000000**4af3246b4fff356261136f113411cb187134D675**

I am getting the output **0x4af3246b4fff356261136f113411cb187134D675**

```
    function bytesToAddress(bytes memory bys) public pure returns (address addr) {

        assembly {
             addr := mload(add(add(bys, 32), 0))
       }
    }
```

Can, anyone explain me, what actually happening ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression `add(bys, 32)`:

Returns a pointer to the actual data, which starts after the first 32 bytes in the `bys` array (those first 32 bytes contain the length of the `bys` array).

---

The expression `mload(x)`:

Loads the data pointed to by `x`, so you can just as well use `mload(add(bys, 32))`, because there is no added value in doing `x + 0`.

---

The expression `addr := y`:

Stores the value of `y` into the variable `addr` (in your case, since the value of `y` is 32-byte long and the type of `addr` is 20-byte long, only the 20 least significant bytes are stored).

Comment: Okay ,but when I am giving 32 bytes (64 characters) input to the function having first 24 characters zeros  ,, how I am getting 20 bytes (40 characters) as output.

Comment: @PardeepThakur: Just as you would whenever you assign a larger-type variable into a smaller-type variable, for example, `uint16 x = 0x1234;` and then `uint8 y = x;`. The value of `y` would be the value of the 8 lower bits of `x`, i.e., `0x34`. The only thing is, that in pure Solidity, the compiler would ask you to explicitly cast `x` to the type of `y`, i.e., `uint8 y = uint8(x);`. And in assembly, the compiler performs the down-cast implicitly.

Comment: @goodvibration forgive me for this noob question, but what does `bys` refer to exactly in `add(bys, 32)`? You can't really add a bytes array type to the number `32` right.

Comment: @rlyx31 You're adding 32bytes to bys which is a pointer to the byte array (basically saying "take the address of my byte array, then add 32 to this address and get what there")

Answer (score 3):

You may meet the following code in many projects:

```
contract A {

    event Log(address addr);

    function() external {
        emit Log(bytesToAddress(msg.data));
    }

    function bytesToAddress(bytes memory source) public pure returns(address addr) {
        assembly {
            addr := mload(add(source, 0x14))
        }
    }
}
```

Actually `source` when meet in assembly refers to 52 bytes:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
4af3246b4fff356261136f113411cb187134D675
```

So shifting 0x14 bytes (20 bytes) means capturing this value:

```
                                        V
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
4af3246b4fff356261136f113411cb187134D675
                                       ^
```

This:

```
0000000000000000000000204af3246b4fff356261136f113411cb187134D675
```

But since return type is address Solidity compiler inserts code to erase top-12 bytes of address:

```
addr = addr & ((1 << 160) - 1)
```

Which leads to:

```
0000000000000000000000204af3246b4fff356261136f113411cb187134D675
&
000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
=
0000000000000000000000004af3246b4fff356261136f113411cb187134D675
                      ^
```

Comment: Shouldn't the bytes type (in this case `source`) have a size that's a multiple of 32 bytes? Instead of the 52 bytes, `source` should be 64 bytes, with 0s appended at the end of the address?

Comment: @rlyx31 for sure, the is padding to 64 with zeroes. But these bytes remain untouched in the proposed schema.

Comment: bytes should be right-padded in calldata, not left-padded